# In geometry nodes, how to switch the collection based on when points start to move?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to make in geometry nodes a bunch of butterflies idle in a tree and then, they start to fly, randomly, at different times. I have 2 collections of animations, idle and flying.
I would like to know how to switch the collection from idle to flying, based on when the points on the surface start to move.

[image: animation gif]

[Blend file](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/6a6468cf0ffe961ee3c4f48398408b2320221122210353/4e8f0f) (133MB, wetransfer.com), uses the [Free GN Presets](https://bradley-animations.gumroad.com/l/jSyDM?layout=profile) addon by Bradley Animations.

Comment: Could you please share your blend file with us (https://blend-exchange.com/) or at least show a screenshot of your *Geometry Nodes* setup? As the question currently stands there, it's almost impossible to give an answer. Thank you!

Comment: Hi. Please don't post essential information like links, file downloads or additional details in the comments section where it can be easily missed. Instead edit them into your original post with the [Edit] button above. Comments are transitory by nature, are hard to index or search for, and may be erased at any moment.